# Configuring tomcat7 in Intellij 12 Ultimate

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a web app using tomcat7 that I want to run from inside IDEA 12.
I've installed tomcat and configured it as app server in idea. 
I've created the artifact (exploded war) and created a run configuration using tomcat.

Starting the run configuration works, the application is deployed and starts fine.

The problem is that I have a context file (tomcat-context.xml) that contains a whole bunch of datasources and I can't seem to get the web app to find that context file.

I have added it in META-INF/ (in the artefact window) and when I look in the output directory I can see that the file is there (with the correct contents). 
I've tried setting the tomcat context descriptor (in the web facet page), using the application context field Run configuration::Deployment tab and nothing worked.

I've checked the location where idea puts the exploded war and the context file is there albeit with a strange name.

When I run the web app with maven (mvn tomcat7:run) it works perfectly.
The pom contains this line:

```
<contextFile>src/test/config/tomcat-context.xml</contextFile>
```

and it's this behaviour I want to replicate.

I'm at my wits end here and open for any ideas.

Comment: Could you please try to add `tomcat-context.xml` to artifact and rename it to `context.xml`?

Comment: Wadda ya know? That actually did work! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Artifacts` -> `Output Layout`, you can rename a file. During deployment, it will copy the file and rename it.

Since usually `Context` elements should be in `META-INF/context.xml`, so just add `tomcat-context.xml` and rename it to `context.xml`.